# Compile a shared library statically

Tags: c++, c, static, linker, shared-libraries

I've got a shared library with some homemade functions, which I compile into my other programs, but I have to link the end program with all the libraries I have used to compile the static library. Here is an example:

I have function `foo` in the library which requires a function from another library `libbar.so`.

In my main program to use function `foo` I have to compile it with the `-lbar` flag. Is there a way I can compile *my* library statically so it includes all the required code from the other libraries, and I can compile my end program without needing the `-lbar` flag?

Comment: Could you explicitly state the platforms in use?  Ideally, they'd be in the tags.

Comment: Side-note; not only would you not have to -lbar, but once you go start, your linker will drop out all of the symbols that *your* code doesn't reference (directly or indirectly down through your call chain).  This will shrink your executable and help your app start up quicker!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shared objects (.so) aren't libraries, they are objects.  You can't extract part of them and insert it in other libraries.

What you can do if build a shared object which references the other -- but the other will be needed at run time.  Just add the -lbar when linking libfoo.

If you are able to build libbar, you can obviously make a library which is the combination of libfoo and libbar.  IIRC, you can also make the linker build a library which is libfoo and the needed part of libbar by linking a .a with the .o meant to go in libbar.  Example:

```
gcc -fPIC -c lib1.c     # define foofn(), reference barfn1()
gcc -fPIC -c lib2a.c    # define barfn1(), reference barfn2()
gcc -fPIC -c lib2b.c    # define barfn2()
gcc -fPIC -c lib2c.c    # define barfn3()
gcc -c main.c           # reference foofn()
ar -cru libbar.a lib2*.o
gcc -shared -o libfoo.so lib1.o -L. -lbar
nm libfoo.so | grep barfn2()    # ok, not here
gcc -o prog main.o -L. -lfoo
env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./prog    # works, so foofn(), barfn1() and barfn2() are found
```

Answer (score 4):

Step 1 (Create object file):

```
gcc -c your.c -o your.o
```

Step 2 (Create static library):

```
ar rcs libyour.a your.o
```

Step 3 (Link against static library):

```
gcc -static main.c -L. -lyour -o statically_linked
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get this sort of thing working by using [libtool](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/), see the [libtool manual on Inter library dependencies](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libtool.html#Inter_002dlibrary-dependencies) for an example of how that works

Answer (score 1):

Basically, if you have the statically-linked libraries of the system libraries that your static library depends on, you can statically-link in all the code from them.

I'm not sure why, though. *NIX platforms' handling of shared libraries is a work of genius, and severely cuts down on compiled program size. If you're worried about not being able to run code on a different computer due to missing libraries, then you can always take the path of most closed-source programs compiled for Linux libraries: just compile them with `-Wl,--rpath -Wl,.` options to GCC and distribute the library alongside the binary.