# Link one shared library static to my shared library

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, linker

I am struggeling a little bit with some options for linking on a project I am currently working on:

I am trying to create a shared library which is linked against 2 other libraries. (Lets call them `libfoo.so` and `libbar.so`)
My output library has to be a shared library and I want to static link `libfoo.so` to the resulting library, but `libbar.so` should linked as a dynamic library. (`libbar.so` should be available on every machine, where `libfoo.so` is not available and I do not want the user install it / ship it with my binaries.)

How could I archive this?

My current build instruction look like this:

```
c++ -Wall -shared -c -o src/lib.o src/lib.cpp
c++ -Wall -shared -o lib.ndll src/lib.o -lfoo -lbar
```

I my defense: I am not a c/c++ expert, so sorry if this question seems to be stupid.

Comment: It seems to me that this is a duplicate  of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812079/compile-a-shared-library-statically/2812137

Comment: I do not have a static version of libfoo.so

Comment: As far as I know, then it isn't possible.  You can double check in the linker manual.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two Linux C/C++ library types.

- Static libraries (`*.a`) are archives of object code which are linked with and becomes part of the application.  They are created with and can be manipulated using the [`ar(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ar) command (i.e. `ar -t libfoo.a` will list the files in the library/archive).
- Dynamically linked shared object libraries (`*.so`) can be used in two ways.

  1. The shared object libraries can be dynamically linked at run time but statically aware. The libraries must be available during compile/link phase. The shared objects are not included into the binary executable but are tied to the execution.
  2. The shared object libraries can be dynamically loaded/unloaded and linked during execution using the dynamic linking loader system functions.

---

In order to statically link `libfoo.so` into your binary, you will need a corresponding static library which is typically called `libfoo.a`.  You can use a static library by invoking it as part of the compilation and linking process when creating a program executable.

The result would be changing your build commands to something like the following:

```
g++ -Wall -fPIC -c -o src/lib.o src/lib.cpp
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,mylib.so.1 -o mylib.so.1 src/lib.o -L/path/to/library-directory -lbar libfoo.a
```