# "dynamically linked at run time but statically aware" - how to control which .so file loaded?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

In reference to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858724/link-one-shared-library-static-to-my-shared-library):

> There are two Linux C/C++ library types.
>
> - Static libraries (`*.a`) are archives of object code which are linked with and becomes part of the application.  They are created
>     with and can be manipulated using the [`ar(1)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858724/link-one-shared-library-static-to-my-shared-library) command (i.e. `ar
>     -t libfoo.a` will list the files in the library/archive).
> - Dynamically linked shared object libraries (`*.so`) can be used in two ways.
>
>   1. The shared object libraries can be dynamically linked at run time but statically aware. The libraries must be available during
>        compile/link phase. The shared objects are not included into the
>        binary executable but are tied to the execution.
>   2. The shared object libraries can be dynamically loaded/unloaded and linked during execution using the dynamic linking loader system
>        functions.

what does it mean to make a **dynamic** lib [tied to the execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858724/link-one-shared-library-static-to-my-shared-library)?

Is this like [Windows manifest files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) that allow the application to load in a specific **dll**?

What's the mechanism to control the **.so** loaded?
There must be such a mechanism otherwise the "compiled" **.so** is the only one ever allowed to be loaded which defeats the purpose of making it **dynamic**?

Comment: In Windows, a potentially simpler-to-understand equivalent would be an [*import library*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682592(v=vs.85).aspx), generated from a module definition file or dll, and linked against whatever module(s) want to pull in the module in question.

Comment: @WhozCraig can you recommend a site that, with diagrams, explains how Linux app loads and uses a **.so** file?

Answer (score 0):

It means that the library is available at link time, so the linker can verify that the functions that you reference from the `.so` are present in the `.so`. The advantage is that calls to these functions are done transparently to you. In other words, if you are linking to an `.so` with

```
int foo(double bar);
```

you call it like this

```
int res = foo(4.2);
```

The linker makes sure that `foo` is there, and that it takes one argument of type `double`. After that it "links" the call site `int res = ...` to the function.

Dynamically loading/unloading during the execution time lets you link without `.so` present on the build system (hence, no "static awareness"). In exchange for this added flexibility you open your system up to a possibility of not finding the functions that you want in the target `.so`. Your calls sequence also look considerably trickier than `foo(4.2)`, because you need to go through `dlopen` preparation step. More info on calling functions from `.so` is in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17081131/335858).